# Tkinter Treeview not displaying the entire str

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a list of tuples with str insides (names of actors). I want to display them in a tkinter Treeview.

But the Treeview display only the First Name. e.i Chritoph instead of Christoph Waltz.

Here's a easily executable code of my issue. I just want the entire str to be displayed.

Thank you!

```
l=[('Amari Cheatom',),('Christoph Waltz',)]

from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
root=Tk()
tableauActeur= Treeview(root)
tableauActeur['columns']='Name'
tableauActeur.heading('Name',text="Name")
tableauActeur['show'] = 'headings'
for i in range(len(l)):
    tableauActeur.insert('','end',iid=l[i][0],values=l[i][0])
tableauActeur.pack(pady=20)
root.mainloop()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try that:

```
for i in range(len(l)):
    tableauActeur.insert('','end',iid=l[i][0],values=l[i]) # [0] prints only the first word
```

Comment: Seems like if a single string is passed as `values` it is automatically `split` and interpreted as a list.

Comment: thanks! It's actually an homework combining SQL and Python to browse a Movie database